# MySQL LIMIT within JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, limits

I have an 1:m association.

`symbols` table has many rows in `company_key_statistics` table. `company_key_statistics` has column `createdAt` which is timestamp indicating when row has been created.
I need to join latest `symbols` with `company_key_statistics`, but I need only latest `company_key_statistics`.
For example I need to get `ORCL` and `MSFT` `symbols` and only their latest `company_key_statistics`.

So far I have tried this.

```
SELECT `symbols`.`id`, 
       `symbols`.`symbol`, 
       `statistics`.
       `marketCapitalization` 
FROM   `symbols` 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `s`.`companyId`, 
                         `s`.`marketCapitalization` 
                  FROM   `company_key_statistics` AS `s`
                  WHERE  `s`.`companyId` = `symbols`.`id` 
                  ORDER by `createdAt` 
                  DESC LIMIT 1) AS `statistics` 
ON     `symbols`.`id` = `statistics`.`companyId` 
WHERE  `symbols`.`symbol` IN ('ORCL', 'SNAP');
```

But unfortunately I found that I can't use columns from parent query in `JOIN` subqueries.

How can I achieve to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sym.id, sym.symbol, s.marketCapitalization 
  FROM symbols AS sym 
  INNER JOIN company_key_statistics AS s 
     ON sym.id = s.companyId 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT companyId, MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt 
                FROM company_key_statistics 
                GROUP BY companyId) AS smax 
     ON smax.companyId = s.companyId AND smax.createdAt = s.createdAt 
  WHERE sym.symbol IN ('ORCL','SNAP');
```

Since your posted example was a `LEFT JOIN`, maybe you want also companies without market capitalization data in your answer. In this case, we have to nest the subselects, in this way:

```
SELECT sym.id, sym.symbol, s.marketCapitalization 
  FROM symbols AS sym 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
               FROM company_key_statistics
               INNER JOIN (SELECT companyId, MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt 
                             FROM company_key_statistics 
                             GROUP BY companyId) AS smax 
               USING (companyId, createdAt)) AS s 
    ON sym.id = s.companyId 
 WHERE sym.symbol IN ('ORCL','SNAP');
```

The general problem we are addressing here is called *groupwise maximum* and many SO and DBA.SE answers deal with it. Check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211479/groupwise-maximum) for instance.

Comment: You don't need nested subqueries. You can use `LEFT` joins with your first query.

Answer (score 4):

For a correlated subquery you should use a CROSS APPLY, unfortunately MySql doesn't allow it, but you can simulate it on this way:

```
SELECT     `symbols`.`id`, 
           `symbols`.`symbol`, 
           `statistics`.
           `marketCapitalization`,
           `s`.`companyId`,
           `s`.`marketCapitalization`  
FROM       `symbols` 
INNER JOIN `company_key_statistics` `s`
ON         `s`.`pk` = (SELECT `pk`          -- the PK of company_key_statistics
                       FROM   `company_key_statistics`
                       WHERE  `companyId` = `symbols`.`id` 
                       ORDER by `createdAt` 
                       DESC LIMIT 1) 
WHERE  `symbols`.`symbol` IN ('ORCL', 'SNAP');
```

You can find some example on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql).

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work since, clause `ON` is same as `s.createdAt = symbols.id` and I got this result http://imgur.com/a/OezQd, as you can see here are 2 `ORCL` rows, but I need only one, which is latest by createdAt

Comment: Between what you think If I select all related statistics and then filter data in my code side of application, is it good approach?

Comment: The `ON` condition needs to be corrected to use `company_key_statistics` pk.